# How to read ResourceDictionary programmatically from another assembly in winrt

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am trying to load ResourceDictionary  from another assembly.

I am able to read a resource file which is in the same assembly by the below lines of code

```
ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary();
rd.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Common/StandardStyles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
object o;
rd.TryGetValue("ColorDarkOrange", out o);
```

Found the below links but these doesn't work well with windows 8 app (Winrt)

[Instantiate ResourceDictionary xaml from other Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548769/instantiate-resourcedictionary-xaml-from-other-assembly)

[ResourceDictionary in a separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/resourcedictionary-in-a-separate-assembly)

Looking forward for help.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing, but appending the assembly name to the front of the Uri?

Comment: tried that too, but no success

Comment: One other thing to try is "ms-appdata"